# Run fail2ban without banning

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, fail2ban

It is possible to run `fail2ban` in some kind of "simulation mode" so it does not ban but log somewhere who it would have ban?

Running fail2ban on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in jail.conf you'll see a line that says this:

```
# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define
# action_* variables. Can be overriden globally or per
# section within jail.local file
banaction = iptables-multiport
```

All the actions are in /etc/action.d/

You could make one that just sends mail.. there are quite a few actions there already that may do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ironically `fail2ban` does not possess a method for performing a "dry-run" or "no-ops" running of the actions defined within. Your only options are to temporarily change the `banaction` that's defined for a specific jail by overriding it for a given jail or do override the actions themselves.

In newer versions of `fail2ban` you can create overrides quite easily by making identically named files with the suffix `.local` instead of `.conf`. You also have access to the `actions.d` and `jail.d` sub-directories where you can put overriding configuration files for a specific jail so that you can redefine values for variables that were previously set, such as `banaction`.

If your `jail.conf` or `jail.local` had this in it:

```
[sshd]

port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
banaction = iptables-multiport
```

You could override this jail like so, by creating a new file under `jail.d` with the following  within it:

```
[sshd]

port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
banaction = iptables-multiport-debug
```

You'd then need to create a corresponding file under `action.d` called, `iptables-multiport-debug.conf`. You could also forgo doing this and simply override the `banaction` file itself in the `action.d` directory. Simply copy the pre-existing `iptables-multipart.conf` file to `iptables-multipart.local`.

**NOTE:** Be careful in doing the 2nd options, since you'll be overriding the `banaction` for any jail that may use it.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answers are still valid, I only wanted to add that there is now action named "dummy.conf" in current fail2ban versions, no need to cook your own. I only had to change the log file location (near the end of the file). Default is to log into `/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.dummy`, which lives on tmpfs.